# Mussarela, Muzzarela, Mozarela or Muçarela?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, estrangeirismos

What is the correct way of writing this word? *Mussarela*, *muzzarela*, *mozarela* or *muçarela*? Did it change with the ["acordo ortográfico"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990)?

Qual a maneira correta de se escrever, *mussarela*, *muzzarela*, *mozarela* or *muçarela*? Algo mudou no ["acordo ortográfico"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990)?

Comment: Assim como a *pizza, piza, pisa, piça*. :)

Comment: @tchrist A escrita *pizza* é tão comum, que eu pessoalmente nunca vi ninguém escrever de outra maneira.

Comment: @tchrist flag, flag, flag! :P

Comment: @tchrist piça?!

Comment: Lateralmente, por que é que _dói_ tanto escrever muçarela após uma vida inteira escrevendo mussarela?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the new *"acordo ortográfico"* (orthographic agreement), promulgated in Brazil in 2009, people started to pay more attention to the spelling of words, and were often surprised to notice that *"mozzarella"* is not written with two `s`. But it is important to know that this spelling was valid even before the "acordo ortográfico".

- **Mozza**, in italian, means curded buffalo or cow milk. This denomination is due to fungal species used to whittle milk, called *"mozze"*.
- **Mozzarella**, italian word and short for *"mozza"*, originated the word "mozarela" in Portuguese. The difference for the word in Italian is the absence of duplicate consonants (`z` and `l`).

To make the spelling of word "mozarela" closer to the spelling in the Portuguese language, a convention already existing in our language was used. The `z` is spelled with `c` or `ç`, as it already happens in several cases, e.g.:

> feliz – felicidade; capaz – capacidade.

Thus, an alternative spelling of "mozarela" is "muçarela" (with `ç` and not with two `s`).

The proper spelling is *mozarela* or *muçarela*.

---

Com o novo acordo ortográfico, promulgado no Brasil em 2009, começou-se a dar mais atenção à grafia das palavras e grande parte das pessoas ficou surpresa ao notarem que *"mozarela"* não se escreve com dois `s`. Mas é importante saber que essa grafia era válida antes mesmo do acordo.

- **Mozza**, em italiano, significa leite de búfala ou de vaca talhado. Essa denominação se deve à espécie de fungo usada para talhar o leite, chamado *"mozze"*.
- **Mozzarella**, palavra em italiano e diminutivo de *"mozza"*, originou a palavra *"mozarela"*, em português. A diferença para a palavra em italiano é a ausência das consoantes duplicadas (`z` e `l`).

Para aproximar mais a grafia da palavra *"mozarela"* da língua portuguesa, recorreu-se a uma convenção já existente em nosso idioma.  O `z`, em diversos termos,é grafado com `c` ou `ç`, como ocorre em casos como:

> feliz – felicidade; capaz – capacidade.

Assim, a outra opção de grafia de *"mozarela"* é escrever *"muçarela"* (com `ç` e não com dois `s`).

Portanto, o adequado é escrever *mozarela* ou *muçarela*.

Source: http://escreverbem.com.br/como-grafar-corretamente-mucarela-mozarela-ou-mussarela/